# aws s3 file upload request timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

```
 var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.file[0].path);
    var fileName = randomInteger+'_'+file.file[0].originalFilename;
    fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err);
            reject(err); 
        }
    });
    fileStream.on('open', function () {
        var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        s3.putObject({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: fileName,
            Body: fileStream,
        }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }else{
                var uploadUrl = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/" + bucketName+ "/" + fileName;
                resolve(uploadUrl);
            }
        });
    });
```

I tried to upload files to s3 bucket but it throws request timeout error
error was threw in the first time of upload if i upload it 2nd 3rd time upload work without any errors

Answer (score 1):

Got answer!!!

This probably because the S3 client is requesting a wrong endpoint region. After the first fail try(us-east-1 as default), the S3 client will update its endpoint with correct region so that the following retries are successful. You can try setting the bucket region in S3 constructor. If the bucket is in eu-west-1, you can construct like this: var s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'eu-west-1'})